# What are the benefits of `let` in Swift?

Tags: performance, swift, constants

I know *Swift* does encourage us programmers to use constants (`let`) instead of variables (`var`) everytime it makes sense.

This is a good thing because we are providing more details to the compiler about what our code means and the compiler can better prevent us from making mistakes (e.g. changing some value that should not be changed).

My question is, are there some **performance optimizations** the compiler does apply when we use **constants instead of variables**? (e.g. faster executions times, lower footprint, ...).

Comment: I don't believe Swift compiler is open source yet. We'll have more insight on your question when the time comes, even then it won't be easy to answer without specific problem at hand.

Comment: Several times Apple explained the compiler optimizations it did. I was wondering if some information about this was available about this topic.

Comment: @A-Live Swift and Obj-C use the same compiler backend which is open source for years and if there are any optimizations on this level, they will be  in the compiler backend, not the frontend (Swift -> LLVM IR).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You asked "...are there some performance optimisations the compiler does apply when we use constants instead of variables?"

The answer is yes, absolutely.

Mutable collections may be organized differently than immutable ones in order to allow for them to be changed. Immutable collections can be optimized for read-only operation.

Then there is the use of mutable/immutable objects. The compiler may have to generate code that copies a mutable object when it's shared as a property of another object in order to avoid undesired side-effects.

Comparison of immutable objects (equatable/comparable) can also be optimized in ways that mutable objects can't.

Sulthan's point about the intelligence of the compiler is a good one though. The compiler can often deduce that a variable is never going to change from code analysis, which can make benchmarking let vs. var usage hard.

Comment: Yes and the title of the question is "What are..." :D

Comment: @appzYourLife, I got called away as I was typing. I hit send and then came back to flesh out my answer when I returned to my computer.

Comment: Oh ok, I thought it was a joke :D Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: Are you talking about *theoretical/possible* performance improvements or did you actually observe the difference?

Comment: @MartinR: Truth to be told I did not make benchmarks. I just had the suspect that Apple implemented some optimizations.

Comment: That puts your answer *"The answer is yes, absolutely."* into a different perspective :)

Comment: Martin, appz was the questioner. My answer is based on my reading and understanding. I have not done a lot of benchmarking, but there is a **strong**, admittedly theoretical, basis to my answer nonetheless.

Comment: There is also technical literature discussing the optimizations the complier can make when it knows the difference between constants and variables

Answer (score 11):

The correct answer for now is "probably not".

Providing additional information to the compiler is always wise, however, the compiler is already rather smart. In many cases it can see that a variable is actually a constant even if you use `var`, so saying `let` won't be any new information and it won't provide a benefit.

The biggest benefit of `const`/`let` is a protection against programming errors. It can have some performance benefits in very specific cases but modern compilers don't really need the programmer to tell them that a variable is assigned only once.