# Swift: Which one of the following code is better performance wise

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

As I know `let` is better over `var` but I am not sure which one of the following is good practice on the performance basis.

```
var edgeValue: Int
var edgeChars: String
var edgeColor: String

if directionUp {
  edgeValue = -5
  edgeChars = "x"
  edgeColor = "red"
} else {
  edgeValue = 5
  edgeChars = "y"
  edgeColor = "green"
}
```

or

```
let edgeValue = directionUp ? -5 : 5
let edgeChars = directionUp ? "x" : "y"
let edgeColor = directionUp ? "red" : "green"
```

Last one is more readable and they are constants but if I have to change `directionUp` to `anotherCondition` in the future then I will need to change it in all lines and it has to calculate or check `directioinUp` on each line run.

I am looking for best code among these two performance wise.

Thanks in advance for all of your answers and suggestions.

Comment: Why is performance important for a situation like this? Do you have a specific performance issue with your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the benefits of \`let\` in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651558/what-are-the-benefits-of-let-in-swift)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson May be there is no performance significance in this small snippet of code but when I keep doing same thing on large scale then performance is important no? So I am trying to figure out which is good because I know ```let``` is best over ```var```

Comment: @RomanPodymov I know ```let``` is best for performance but I am looking for above situation.

Comment: What large scale? Maybe you should concentrate on writing code that is most suitable for your use-case now and worry about performance later. Compared to other stuff like networking or database access or UI updates the difference here might be completely irrelevant from a performance perspective.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your suggestion about not worrying much about performance initially.

Answer (score 3):

Both solutions end up being compiled to assembly code, that has multiple steps:

- Memory allocation
- Copy those value L1, L2, ... in CPU
- Comparation
  ...

Assembly code looks like below:

```
MOV AX,5h
MOV BX,5h
SUB AX,BX 
JZ EQUALS
JNZ NOTEQUALS

EQUALS:
MOV CL,'Y'
JMP PRINT

NOTEQUALS:
MOV CL,'N'

PRINT:
MOV AH,2
MOV DL,CL
INT 21H

RET
```

This solution looks elegant but it cost more steps to execute than the others,
comparing `directionUp` three time as example.

```
let edgeValue = directionUp ? -5 : 5
let edgeChars = directionUp ? "x" : "y"
let edgeColor = directionUp ? "red" : "green"
```

Comment: Thank! I was looking for this kind of answer.

Comment: So do you think this one is best 
```let (edgeValue, edgeChars, edgeColor) = directionUp ? (-5, "x", "red") : (5, "5", "green")``` as ```diretionUp``` is executed only once. Answered by @Володимир

Comment: Yeah, I think that my solution will be faster - here we have three comparitions, that took processor's ticks. But in mobile and computer development this will means few microseconds of operation time - You will not recognize the difference, so it is better to look for a more readable code.

Comment: I think @Володимир's solution is the best, it's effienct and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

There are three criteria of performance:

a) speed of computation

b) less amount of used memory

c) quicker reading and understanding code for any developer (as result it is in demand of commercial code, were big team must write down big project and recheck each other)

For quickest performance it is:

```
 let edgeValue: Int
 let edgeChars: String
 let edgeColor: String

 (edgeValue, edgeChars, edgeColor) = directionUp ? 
       (-5, "x", "red") :
       (5, "5", "green")
```

For quicker usage code (reading and understand it) looks better to connect all this data into one structure:

```
struct Edge{
   let value: Int
   let chars: String
   let color: String
}

let edge = directionUp ? 
       Edge(value: -5, chars: "x", color: "red") :
       Edge(value: 5, chars: "5", color: "green")
```

This structure take additional 4 bytes of memory and few ticks of processor performance for each call to any property, but it is more comfortable to work with few similar structures than to try remember of all variables in each class.

Anyway - if this values will not be changed - use let, for clearing your code and forbidding to change this value

Comment: OP is asking about best performance, I see no reference to performance in this answer?

Comment: Don't reply tom me, add this to your answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make `let`, not `var`:

```
let edgeValue: Int
let edgeChars: String
let edgeColor: String

if directionUp {
    edgeValue = -5
    edgeChars = "x"
    edgeColor = "red"
} else {
    edgeValue = 5
    edgeChars = "y"
    edgeColor = "green"
}
```

Just replace `var` with `let` in your first code snippet. You initialise `edgeValue`, `edgeChars` and `edgeColor` only once.

Comment: OP is asking about best performance, I see no reference to performance in this answer?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson In such case it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31651558/what-are-the-benefits-of-let-in-swift.

Comment: declaring a constant with let require it has to be initialized, this will cause syntax errors

Comment: @duytph In my answer all constants are initialised only once, it has no syntax errors.

Comment: @duytph read https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html (chapter "Constant Declaration"):
`When a constant is declared at global scope, it must be initialized with a value. When a constant declaration occurs in the context of a function or method, it can be initialized later, as long as it is guaranteed to have a value set before the first time its value is read. If the compiler can prove that the constant’s value is never read, the constant isn’t required to have a value set at all.`